# How do I use hook_preprocess_page_title() on a Bootstrap subtheme?

Tags: 8, bootstrap-theme

I've just discovered that Drupal 8 Bootstrap theme doesn't implement all existent hooks.
So, for example, `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()` works, but
`hook_theme_suggestions_node_alter()` doesn't work.

I'm interested on `hook_preprocess_page_title(&$variables)` and I wonder if it's possible to incorporate this hook into my custom Bootstrap sub-theme. I have created the *page-title.html.twig* template and cleared the cache.

I saw https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!plugins!Preprocess.md/group/plugins_preprocess/8.x-3.x but it seems this is for extending an already existent hook in Bootstrap theme, not for adding a new one.

How do I add `hook_preprocess_page_title()` in a Bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add hook_preprocess_page_title() in a Bootstrap theme?

In your sub-theme's **.theme** file you add:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page_title()
 */
SUB_THEME_NAME_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  // your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: as I mentioned before that doesn't work on my Bootstrap subtheme :-/

Comment: Did you check if the hook is firing? ex: put inside of it `\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('testing.'), 'error');`

Comment: yes, I've checked it and the hook is not being fired, i answer because of this.